What did Jesus mean in Matthew 7:21-23?
Jesus said,

"“Not everyone who says to Me, ‘Lord, Lord!’ will enter the kingdom of
heaven, but only the one who does the will of My Father in heaven. On
that day many will say to Me, ‘Lord, Lord, didn’t we prophesy in Your
name, drive out demons in Your name, and do many miracles in Your
name?’ Then I will announce to them, ‘I never knew you! Depart from
Me, you lawbreakers!’"

What is God's will? These men had good credentials which obviously meant nothing concerning Jesus.

This question is similar to: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/60169/how-are-we-to-understand-jesus-words-in-matthew-721-23-and-how-they-were-to-b

The problem Jesus was bringing out was how some people will seek to justify themselves on the Day of Judgment. They will present good works that they have done as reasons why they really are Christians. And, exemplary ones at that. They will expect to be acclaimed by Christ for what they consider to be the good works of:
Prophesying in Christ's name.
Casting out demons in Christ's name.
Doing miracles in Christ's name.
Spectacular stuff! The sort of amazing things promoted by many religious television programmes these days. The sort of predominant events at many 'charismatic'-type services. Things that people are supposed to hear and see and feel, in order to get them joining up with groups promoting that sort of thing. Emotions excited. Total attention grabbed. Money then filling the plates and boxes of such groups.
But let the Bible bring us back down to chilling reality. Here is a stark warning that contains the answer to this question:

"For I am not ashamed of the gospel of Christ: for it is the power of
God unto salvation to every one that believeth; to the Jew first, and
also to the Greek. For therein is the righteousness of God revealed
from faith to faith. For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven
against all ungodliness and unrighteousness of men, who hold the truth
in unrighteousness." Romans 1:16-18 A.V.

There is stated the will of God - to believe the gospel of Christ; that is what saves people who believe it. They discover in it their total unrighteousness, and that only the righteousness of God gives life, by faith - not by doing things people think show themselves to be righteous.
Matthew 7:21-23 is a warning given by Christ about those who "hold the truth in unrighteousness". They boast of what they have done, which they consider will justify them before God - which will make other people think, "Oh, what fine, righteous Christians those wonder-working people are!" But Christ is never fooled.
Those who have believed, and who are not ashamed of the gospel of Christ, have saving faith, and seek out God's will so that they might do it, day by day. It's not that miracles are out of the question. Sometimes the Lord will use one of his children to do a genuine miracle in his name. But you won't find them boasting about it, or speaking of it so as to impress others. Beware the wonder-workers who present their idea of Christianity by means of what they do.
God's will is always for us to point to Christ alone for salvation; to live for Christ, daily picking up our cross, to repeat the biblical gospel of salvation so that others will see "Christ in you, the hope of glory" (Colosians 1:27) and believe in Christ.

The people were making claims, saying they had done things in Jesus' name.  The Holy Spirit recorded what they would say, but that does not make those claims true. We always have to discern who is speaking in the Scriptures. If God or His prophets / messengers, apostles are speaking then we know that is truth.  If men are speaking we always have to allow that their words might not be true.  Abraham spoke a half-truth when he claimed Sarah was his sister.
Just because men would make claims of doing things in Jesus' name does not mean that they were doing God's will.
Matt. 7:23 is better translated in the YLT:

and then I will acknowledge to them, that -- I never knew you, depart from me ye who are working lawlessness.

Lawlessness, not just law breakers, but those who were outside the God's command.  They were not known to Jesus.  When He said that He never knew them He was saying that they had never been immersed into Christ.  Therefore, whatever "works" they claimed to have done in His name were not authorized by Him, as they were not in His kingdom, and were not able to act in His name.
Only those that do the will of our Father in heaven know Him.  What did Jesus say?

for whoever may do the will of my Father who is in the heavens, he is my brother, and sister, and mother.' (Matt. 12:50, YLT)

And, the will of the Father was to be immersed into Christ for the forgiveness of our sins (Mark 16:16; Acts 2:38; 1 Cor. 12:13; Gal. 3:27; Matt. 22:37-39).  Until we are in Christ we cannot say that we know Him.  We cannot act in His name, or by His authorization until we are covered by His blood because only then do we become His priests and ambassadors on this earth (1 Pet. 2:9; 2 Cor. 5:20; Rev. 5:10).
